# How to show a field when user click on save button?

Tags: apex, visualforce, community, force

I have a standard field called Product Brief Number ({!Product_Brief__c.Name}).     This field is Auto Number, after saving it will generate a number. I want show this field when some after click on the save button. Otherwise my page will break.

```
   <apex:outputText value="{!Product_Brief__c.Name}"></apex:outputText>

   <apex:pageblockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}"/>
                <apex:commandButton value="Print" onclick="window.print();"/>
                <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!Cancel}"/>
    </apex:pageblockButtons>
```

Any one have any suggestions How to do that? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use rendered attribute in your outputText to show and hide your field.

```
<apex:outputText value="{!Product_Brief__c.Name}" rendered="{!IF(Product_Brief__c != NULL && Product_Brief__c.Name != NULL,true,false)}">
</apex:outputText>
```

Provide a id to outputText and rerender this id in your commandbutton

```
<apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}" rerender="outputTextId"/>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but i don't think this is going to work. Coz I already using  rerender properties in my page. If i add above part it will break my page. Thanks again